# Disable selection only on the first item in kendo list view

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a Kendo list view that displays list of candidates with list view selection mode set to multiple. I would want to disallow selection of only the first item in the list. In other words, apart from the first item in the list view, all other items are selectable. Please suggest with sample jQuery code on how to achieve  it.

Thanks and regards,
Damodar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
 $("#listView div:first-child").toggleClass('k-selectable');
```

Hope this helps!

UPDATE :

In order to select the first item, you need to add the following code :

```
var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
listView.select(listView.element.children().first());
```

UPDATE2:

To keep the item selected irrespctive of what changes, handle the change event of the grid as follows :

```
change: function() {
      if(!(this.element.children().first().hasClass('k-state-selected')))
        {this.select(this.element.children().first());}      
    }
```

Comment: Now I have a change in requirement, I need to preselect the first item in the list and from there on lock down the first item and make it not de-selectable, it should stay selected. I tried adding class ".addClass('k-state-selected')". It did not work. Please suggest on how to do this.

Comment: Will the further items be selected by holding Ctrl + click? That is the only way you can select multiple items.

Comment: Correct, further items can be selected by holding Ctrl + click. But the first item should always stay selected, the user should not be able to unselect it.

Comment: Tried it Srinivas, this selects the first item while the page loads but I am able to unselect the first item by ctrl + click. I need to keep the first item as selected always and should not be unselect-able even on ctrl + click.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem... Try this dojo I have created (http://trykendoui.telerik.com/uKIN). I want to remind you that the first item will be unselected if you attempt to select other elements without ctrl + click. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: ok, yes that's the problem. The first items gets unselected when selecting other elements without ctrl + click. Could we retain the selection on first item even when the second item is selected by just clicking.

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer... check this dojo (http://trykendoui.telerik.com/uKIN/3)

Comment: Perfect, this works as intended. Thanks Srinivas :) But sorry, I am unable to up vote as a message prompts vote up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: Sure no problem... glad I could be of help :)